# Receiving 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS Code=2' in an Obj-C to Swift Conversion

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8, xcode6

I am receiving the error 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2,address=0x16fcbbfec)' in my TimeView Controller on the line

```
var soundEffects = SoundEffects()
```

and I have no idea why this is happening...

I have provided the link to my source code for anyone who is willing to take a look and help me out. Thanks!

https://github.com/JohnnyH1012/HRC

Relevant code

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class SoundEffects: NSObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    var soundEffects = SoundEffects()
    var player = AVAudioPlayer()
    var storage = SettingsStorage()
    var enabled:Bool = false
    var newValue:Bool = true
    var tabata: Tabata!
    var theme: Theme!

func registerSoundEffects() {

    soundEffects = SoundEffects.new()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(soundEffects, selector: "stateChanged:", name: StateChanged, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(soundEffects, selector: "prepareSignal:", name: PrepareSignal, object: nil)

    var error:NSError?

    var url: NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("beep_01", ofType: "mp3")!)!

    player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: &error)
    player.numberOfLoops = 0
    player.prepareToPlay()
    enabled = storage.loadSoundEnabled()

}

func isEnabled() {

    return enabled = true

}

func setEnabled() {
    enabled = newValue
    storage.saveSoundEnabled(newValue)

}

func stateChanged(notification: NSNotification) {
    if enabled {

        var tabata: Tabata! = notification.object! as! Tabata
        switch tabata.getState() {
        case .EXERCISE: fallthrough
        case .RELAXATION:
            player.play()
            break

        default:
            break

        }
    }
}

func prepareSignal(notification:NSNotification) {

    if enabled {
        player.play()
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite recursive loop. When you initialize a `SoundEffects`, it initializes its `soundEffects` variable, which initializes a `SoundEffects` object, which initializes `soundEffects` var, which...

You see the problem?

Comment: Yes, but how would this be fixed?

Comment: Well, I'd need you to explain your intentions with having a class that contains a reference to an instance of itself in a variable.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, I retrieved the timer project off of Github and am trying to make sense of the authors work.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an conflict with the `setEnabled` setter. In Swift there are property observers which are called after a variable is set.

Delete the `isEnabled()` and `setEnabled()` method use the variable `enabled` this way also as getter

```
var enabled: Bool = false {
    didSet {
       storage.saveSoundEnabled(newValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: Implementing what you suggested results in the 'fun stateChanged(notification: NSNotification)' giving a "expected 'get', 'set', 'willSet', or 'didSet' keyword to start an accessor definition" error

Comment: there is a brace missing at the end, I edited the post

Comment: Alright, thanks for fixing that, but the app still crashes with the same error.